# distance between nodes in floyd warshall

Tags: algorithm, floyd-warshall

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)wikipedia page explains the Floyd Warshall algorithm to find the shortest path between nodes in a graph.  The wikipedia page uses the graph on the left of the image [image: uses the graph on the left of the image] as a starting graph (prior to the first iteration when k = 0) and then shows the remaining iterations (k = 1 etc) but it doesn't explain the significance of the numbers between the nodes and how those numbers are calculated. For example, in the starting graph when k = 0 why is there a -2 on the edge between 1 and 3, and why is there a 3 on the edge between 2 and 3. How are those calculated?

Furthermore, when k = 2, the wikipedia page says,

> The path [4,2,3] is not considered, because [2,1,3] is the shortest
>   path encountered so far from 2 to 3.

Why is [2,1,3] shorter than [4,2,3]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers on the edges are just weights. It's a part of the input. The algorithm doesn't compute them.

[2, 1, 3] is not shorter than [4, 2, 3]. It's shorter than [2, 3], though. That's the only thing that matters.

Comment: ok, why is [2,1,3] shorter than [2,3]? because 2->1 (4 weight) and 1 -> 3 (-2 weight) equals 2 (total weight), versus [2,3] which is 3?

Comment: @Leahcim Yes. The length of the path is the sum of its edges' weights.